# Suggest an exhaustive procedure that will find a separating vector for linearly separable pattern in a finite number of steps

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, neural-networks, classification, separation

I read in a pattern classification text, that if we consider weight vectors whose components are integer valued, the perceptron procedure would terminate in a finite number of steps.

What is the intuition and theory behind this?

**EDIT:** It is a homework problem from the text book [Pattern classification](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0471056693.html) by Duda, Hart, Stork, and I just wanted a hint, so posted the above query. Here is the actual homework problem:

> Let ${y_{1},...,y_{n}}$ be a finite set of linearly separable samples
>   in d dimensions. Suggest an exhaustive procedure that will find a
>   separating vector in a finite number of steps. (You might wish to
>   consider weight vectors whose components are integer valued.)

Comment: Can you add some more details? I don't know how exactly you would apply the learning rule to only allow for integer values. How exactly do you round off etc.?

Comment: I have updated my question with more details

Comment: It seems you could use the result of [your previous question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14916/how-can-it-be-proved-that-if-number-of-samples-are-less-than-d1-then-the-samp) to develop a brute force $O((n-d-1)\binom{n}{d+1})$ algorithm.

Comment: Thanks! Will post the post the solution, to close the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can it be proved that if number of samples are less than $d+1$, then the sample set is linearly separable?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14916/how-can-it-be-proved-that-if-number-of-samples-are-less-than-d1-then-the-sam)